# Programmatically change react component being displayed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

I'm trying to have a page that switches out which component is rendered based off of a pair of navigation buttons. The page is set up like this

```
ReactDOM.render(<Logo/>, document.getElementById('logo'));
ReactDOM.render(<Upload/>, document.getElementById('main'));
ReactDOM.render(<NavButtons/>, document.getElementById('nav_buttons'))
ReactDOM.render(<Footer />, document.getElementById('footer'));
```

The `<Upload/>` component is the one I wish to cycle out. So when the user pressed the 'next' navigation button a different component would then be loaded on the page.

How do you go about this? Am I attacking this problem correctly? I am new to react so trying to figure out the best way to utilize it.

**Ended up using both answers below for different use cases. Both work to accomplish this though.**

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 3):

Your use case can be achieved by changing the internal state of the parent container  on user clicks and rendering different child components by checking which component to render based on the state value.

Since, you are new to react, I don't even know if u get the point. Go through react docs about state, props and lifecycles before starting to code in react.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 3):

Use react router and dynamically update the Link in next button then you will able to get the next component

Example:-

```
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.increaseIndexValue=this.increaseIndexValue.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      "nextIndex":1,
      "componentArray" : ["Logo", "Upload", "NavButtons", "Footer"],
    }
    increaseIndexValue(){
    const {nextIndex, componentArray} = this.state;
    if(nextIndex == 1){
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return {nextIndex: prevState.nextIndex + 1}
        });
    }
    else if (nextIndex >1 && nextIndex < componentArray.length-1) {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {nextIndex: prevState.nextIndex + 1}
      });
    }
    else if (nextIndex == componentArray.length -1) {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {nextIndex: 3 }
      });
    }
  }
    <Router>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Logo} />
            <Route path="/Logo" component={Logo} />
            <Route path="/Upload" component={Upload} />
            <Route path="/NavButtons" component={NavButtons} />
            <Route path="/Footer" component={Footer} />
         <Link to={"/"+componentArray[nextIndex]}><a href="" className="next" onClick={this.increaseIndexValue}>Next &raquo;</a></Link>

      </Router>
```